# How to use SharedPreferences in Bloc Pattern?

Tags: dart, flutter, sharedpreferences

I am trying to use shared preference in my app with the bloc pattern.
Following is my code

```
class PrefsStats {
  final bool isMale;
  final String name;
  final int age;

  PrefsStats(this.isMale, this.name, this.age);
}

class PrefsBloc {

  final _changePrefernce = BehaviorSubject<PrefsStats>();
  Function(PrefsStats) get changePrefs => _changePrefernce.sink.add;
  Stream<PrefsStats> get prefrence => _changePrefernce.stream;
  SharedPreferences sPrefs;

  dispose(){
    _changePrefernce?.close();
  }

  PrefsBloc(){
    _loadSharedPreferences();
  }

  Future<void> _loadSharedPreferences() async {
    sPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final namePref = sPrefs.getString("name") ?? "";
    final malePref = sPrefs.getBool("male") ?? false;
    final agePref = sPrefs.getInt("age") ?? 0;
    _changePrefernce.add(PrefsStats(malePref,namePref,agePref));
  }



}

final prefsBloc = PrefsBloc();
```

I just want to insert data using one button and get data using another button from `SharedPreferences`

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                prefsBloc.changePrefs(PrefsStats(true, "argo", 21));
              },
              child: Text("Insert Data"),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
              prefsBloc.prefrence.forEach((data){
                print(data.name);
              });
              },
              child: Text("Get Data"),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    prefsBloc?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Whenever I close my app and reopen it again and I click get data button at the start even before inserting data, I get default values. I know I am not assigning keys at the time of setting value, which is causing the confusion of how to use shared preferences with bloc. And the other problem is whenever I set data, the code inside get data button gets called even before pressing get data which I fail to understand.

Comment: check out last episode of official flutter development show https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-My77Yc27g, it's exactly about your question

Comment: @nucleartux actually I tried using sharedprefernces with bloc after seeing that episode and the example they demonstrate in that episode is very simple

Answer (score 2):

There exits two places on your code that must be fixed.
First of all, in your BloC class, your stream must Listen whenever a sink is added,

```
.
.
.
PrefsBloc(){
_loadSharedPreferences();
_changePrefernce.stream.listen(_newFunction);

}

void _newFunction(PrefsStats stats){
   if (states != null) {
      if (sPrefs != null) {
         sPrefs.setString("name", states.name);
         sPrefs.setInt("age", states.age);
         sPrefs.setBool("male", states.isMale);
         sPrefs.commit();
      }
   }
}
```

Second place is in _MyAppState class, in the build function you have to wrap Scaffold with a StreamBuilder,

```
      class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
        String textAge = "";
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return MaterialApp(
              home: StreamBuilder(
            stream: prefsBloc.prefrence,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<PrefsStats> snapshot) {
              return Scaffold(
                body: SafeArea(
                    child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text((snapshot.data != null) ? snapshot.data.name : ""),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        prefsBloc.changePrefs(PrefsStats(
                          true,
                          textAge.toString(),
                          21,
                        ));
                      },
                      child: Text("Insert Data"),
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      initialValue: (snapshot.data != null) ? snapshot.data.name : "",
                      onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                        textAge = value;
                      },
                    ),
                    Text(textAge),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        prefsBloc.prefrence.forEach((data) {
                          print(data.name);
                          setState(() {
                            textAge = data.name;
                          });
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text("Get Data"),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
              );
            },
          ));
        }
```